FFmpeg, using CUDA, reports an error when using the concat filter
I have a ffmpeg command with Nvidia hardware support with which I want to join two videos:
/home/videotest/ffmpeg-dev/ffmpeg -benchmark -hide_banner -loglevel warning -y -hwaccel_device 0 -hwaccel cuda -hwaccel_output_format cuda -i /mnt/video-storage/test/cuda/surfing/intermediate1.mp4 -i /mnt/video-storage/test/cuda/surfing/intermediate2. mp4 -filter_complex 'hwupload_cuda,[0:v:0][0:a:0][1:v:0][1:a:0]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1 [outv] [outa]' -map [outv] -map [outa] -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:v h264_nvenc -preset p6 -profile: v high -force_key_frames 'expr:gte(t,n_forced*5)' -bf 0 -movflags +faststart -b:v 3000k -maxrate 4000k /mnt/video-storage/test/cuda/surfing/game.mp4

I get an error message after starting:
Impossible to convert between the formats supported by the filter 'graph 0 input from stream 0:0' and the filter 'auto_scale_0'
[fc#0 @ 0x61ae2b37a1c0] Error reinitializing filters!

If I use nvdec/nvenc instead of CUDA, this error does not appear and the video is created fine.
I can't figure out how to remove it. Can you help me?

concat filter is a "CPU filter", so we can't use it when video is uploaded to the GPU.
A simple solution is using CPU decoder (without -hwaccel cuda) and GPU encoder (using -c:v h264_nvenc):
ffmpeg -hide_banner -loglevel warning -y -i intermediate1.mp4 -i intermediate2.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v:0][0:a:0][1:v:0][1:a:0]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1" -c:v h264_nvenc -preset p6 -profile:v high -bf 0 -movflags +faststart -b:v 3000k -maxrate 4000k game.mp4

In case we like to decode both input videos using GPU decoder, we have to download the video to the CPU before using concat filter, and upload after:
ffmpeg -hide_banner -loglevel warning -y -hwaccel cuda -hwaccel_output_format cuda -i intermediate1.mp4 -hwaccel cuda -hwaccel_output_format cuda -i intermediate2.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v:0]hwdownload[v0];[1:v:0]hwdownload[v1];[v0][0:a:0][v1][1:a:0]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[tmpv][outa];[tmpv]format=nv12,hwupload_cuda[outv]" -map "[outv]" -map "[outa]" -c:v h264_nvenc -preset p6 -profile:v high -bf 0 -movflags +faststart -b:v 3000k -maxrate 4000k game.mp4
